# Generate test data in Oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors, ora-06550

I want to create test data for these Oracle tables:

```
CREATE TABLE AGENT_HISTORY(
  EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  AGENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_DATE DATE NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE CPU_HISTORY(
  CPU_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CPU_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  CPU_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/
```

Can you help me to create procedure for generating random values for 100 rows?

I tried this

```
BEGIN

  FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO AGENT_HISTORY (EVENT_ID, AGENTID, EVENT_DATE)
    VALUES (loop_counter, 22, SYSDATE);
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;   

  FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO CPU_HISTORY_ID (CPU_HISTORY_ID, EVENT_ID, CPU_NAME, CPU_VALUE)
    VALUES (loop_counter, loop_counter, 'cpu1', dbms_random.value(1,100));
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

But I get these errors:

```
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADMIN.KEY8) violated
ORA-06512: at line 5
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 16:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 5, column 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Closing because you don't like the fact that someone wants code is not a reason to close.

Comment: `INSERT INTO CPU_HISTORY_ID` remove the `_ID` to use the table name `CPU_HISTORY`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps (see below working SQLfiddle)

```
INSERT INTO AGENT_HISTORY (EVENT_ID,AGENTID,EVENT_DATE)
select 
 trunc(dbms_random.value(1,100)) EVENT_ID ,
 trunc(dbms_random.value(1,100)) AGENTID ,
 TO_DATE(
          TRUNC(
               DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2000-01-01','J')
                                ,TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-11-10','J')
                                )
                ),'J'
           ) EVENT_DATE from dual
connect by level <=10;

select * from AGENT_HISTORY
```

Working SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bcb6/7

Comment: Are you sure? I can't list any data later when I browse the table with sqldeveloper

Comment: @peter-penzov Corrected. One line of code (`insert ...`) was missing. Also now I improved `dbms_random.value` and introduced a more better random date.

Comment: Can you please show me for the second table CPU_HISTORY what SQL query I need to execute?

Comment: I added an answer with few hints.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the PK sequentially (using rownum), if you want random order, add order by clause.
This saves you from the duplicated keys.

```
 select 
  rownum CPU_HISTORY_ID,
  trunc(dbms_random.value(1,50)) EVENT_ID,
  'CPU NO '||trunc(dbms_random.value(1,10)) CPU_NAME,
  dbms_random.value(1,5) CPU_VALUE
 from dual connect by level <= 100 
 order by dbms_random.value()
 ;
```

If the foreign key is simple e.g. any number from 1 to 50 use the random number generator as above.
If you have a predefined set of possible values, use a lookup table.
In the example below the table EVENT maps integer 1..3 to the possible EVENT_IDs to fullfill the FK constraints. Use similar approach for your event table.

```
 with event as (
    select 1 rn, 1828 EVENT_ID from dual union all
    select 2 rn, 2818 EVENT_ID from dual union all
    select 3 rn, 9898 EVENT_ID from dual),
 gendata as (   
 select 
  rownum CPU_HISTORY_ID,round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) rn,
  'CPU NO '||trunc(dbms_random.value(1,10)) CPU_NAME,
  dbms_random.value(1,5) CPU_VALUE
 from dual connect by level <= 100 
 )
 select CPU_HISTORY_ID,   
  (select EVENT_ID from event where rn = gendata.rn) EVENT_ID,
   CPU_NAME, CPU_VALUE
 from gendata
 order by dbms_random.value()
 ;
```